# 1D cubic and linear Interpolation in python

Tags: python-2.7, scipy

I would like to interpolate 8 data points from `-2.5 to 2.0` by using the `np.linspace()` command and fully understand that the numbers should be non-negative but however when i run my codes I get an error which says `raise ValueError("x and y arrays must be equal in length along "
ValueError: x and y arrays must be equal in length along interpolation axis.` Here are my codes:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d


X = np.linspace(-2.5, 2.0, num=8, endpoint=True)
Y = np.linspace(1, 44, num=44, endpoint=True)

f = interp1d(X,Y)
f2 = interp1d(X, Y, kind='cubic')

Xnew = np.linspace(-2.5, 2.0, num=44, endpoint=True)

plt.plot(X, Y, 'o', Xnew, f(Xnew), Xnew, f2(Xnew), '--'  )
plt.legend(['data', 'linear', 'cubic'], loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just as the exception reads you provided arrays of different length.

Take a look at this part of documentation:

> num : int, optional
>   Number of samples to generate. Default is 50. Must be non-negative.

```
X = np.linspace(-2.5, 2.0, num=8, endpoint=True)
Y = np.linspace(1, 44, num=44, endpoint=True)
```

You generate 8 X values and 44 Y values. Considering the length mismatch there is no explicit way to generate (x, y) points.
If you choose the same num for every array, you get a working script.